# Не работает тестовый платёж кошелька Яндекс Денег

Tags: java, spring, yandex-money

Я работаю с API кошелька Яндекс Денег. Хочу согласно документации Яндекс денег сделать тестовый платёж, указав параметр test_payment test_payment. Вот мой Код:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/successPayment", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String   testMethod(@RequestParam(value = "code", required = true) String code
            /* HttpSession session,*/

    ) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        //https://money.yandex.ru/oauth/authorize?client_id=id_application&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/successPayment&scope=payment.to-account("numberCosehelek").limit(,20)

        //Get Token

       URL urlgetAccessToken = new URL(" https://money.yandex.ru/oauth/token");
        Map<String,Object> paramsForToken = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        paramsForToken.put("code",code);
        paramsForToken.put("client_id", "id_app");
        paramsForToken.put("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        paramsForToken.put("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8080/successPayment");


        StringBuilder postDataForToken = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : paramsForToken.entrySet()) {
            if (postDataForToken.length() != 0) postDataForToken.append('&');
            postDataForToken.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postDataForToken.append('=');
            postDataForToken.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytesForToken = postDataForToken.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection connForToken = (HttpURLConnection)urlgetAccessToken.openConnection();
        connForToken.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connForToken.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connForToken.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytesForToken.length));
        connForToken.setDoOutput(true);
        connForToken.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytesForToken);

        Reader inForToken = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connForToken.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sbForToken = new StringBuilder();
        for (int cForToken; (cForToken = inForToken.read()) >= 0;)
            sbForToken.append((char)cForToken);
        String responseForToken = sbForToken.toString();

        ObjectMapper mapperForToken = new ObjectMapper();
        AccessToken accessToken = mapperForToken.readValue(responseForToken.toString(), AccessToken.class);

        String token=accessToken.getAccess_token();

        //request-payment

        URL urlRequestPayment = new URL(" https://money.yandex.ru/api/request-payment");
        Map<String,Object> paramsForRequestPayment = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        paramsForRequestPayment.put("pattern_id","p2p");
      
        paramsForRequestPayment.put("to", "numberCoshelek");
        paramsForRequestPayment.put("amount", 20.00);
        paramsForRequestPayment.put("message", "perevod");
        paramsForRequestPayment.put("comment", "perevod");

        paramsForRequestPayment.put("test_payment", true);
        paramsForRequestPayment.put("test_result", "success");



        StringBuilder postDataRequestPayment = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : paramsForRequestPayment.entrySet()) {
            if (postDataRequestPayment.length() != 0) postDataRequestPayment.append('&');
            postDataRequestPayment.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postDataRequestPayment.append('=');
            postDataRequestPayment.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytesRequestPayment = postDataRequestPayment.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        String bearer=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(token.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).replaceAll("(\n)", "");

        HttpURLConnection connForRequestPayment = (HttpURLConnection)urlRequestPayment.openConnection();
        connForRequestPayment.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connForRequestPayment.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
        connForRequestPayment.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connForRequestPayment.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytesRequestPayment.length));
        connForRequestPayment.setDoOutput(true);
        connForRequestPayment.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytesRequestPayment);

        Reader inRequestPayment = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connForRequestPayment.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sbForRequestPayment = new StringBuilder();
        for (int cForRequestPayment; (cForRequestPayment = inRequestPayment.read()) >= 0;)
            sbForRequestPayment.append((char)cForRequestPayment);
        String responseForRequestPayment = sbForRequestPayment.toString();

        ObjectMapper mapperRequestPayment = new ObjectMapper();
        RequestPayment requestPayment = mapperRequestPayment.readValue(responseForRequestPayment.toString(), RequestPayment.class);

        String requestId=requestPayment.getRequest_id();

        URL urlProcessPayment = new URL(" https://money.yandex.ru/api/process-payment");
        Map<String,Object> paramsForProcessPayment = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        paramsForProcessPayment.put("request_id",requestId);




        StringBuilder postDataProcessPayment = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : paramsForProcessPayment.entrySet()) {
            if (postDataProcessPayment.length() != 0) postDataProcessPayment.append('&');
            postDataProcessPayment.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postDataProcessPayment.append('=');
            postDataProcessPayment.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytesProcessPayment = postDataProcessPayment.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection connForProcessPayment = (HttpURLConnection)urlProcessPayment.openConnection();
        connForProcessPayment.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connForProcessPayment.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
        connForProcessPayment.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connForProcessPayment.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytesProcessPayment.length));
        connForProcessPayment.setDoOutput(true);
        connForProcessPayment.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytesProcessPayment);

        Reader inProcessPayment = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connForProcessPayment.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sbForProcessPayment = new StringBuilder();
        for (int cForProcessPayment; (cForProcessPayment = inProcessPayment.read()) >= 0;)
            sbForProcessPayment.append((char)cForProcessPayment);
        String responseForProcessPayment = sbForProcessPayment.toString();

        ObjectMapper mapperProcessPayment = new ObjectMapper();
        ProcessPayment processPayment= mapperProcessPayment.readValue(responseForProcessPayment.toString(), ProcessPayment.class);

        return responseForRequestPayment;


    }
```

Но я получаю следующий результат:

```
{
error: "not_enough_funds",
status: "refused"
}
```

Недостаточно средств. Дело в том, что у меня на счету ничего нет. Но как я понял тестовый платёж не предполагает перевода никаких денег.Но у меня он не работает. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой.